# Indexed query execution jumps from seconds to hours with a minimal increase in data

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures, indexing, innodb

I am experiencing great performance until a point where my query jumps from seconds to hours.

What can I do to A) investigate B) resolve a major performance bottleneck when querying too much data on Mysql?

Perhaps memory related?

---

#### Results

In testing the performance of a stored procedure I ran it twice within 5 minutes, first...

```
mysql> CALL TopFromBigTable('2012-04-01','2012-05-01',5);
5 rows in set (23.76 sec)
```

Which is extremely fast but then I call it again and ... I killed it after well over an hour!

```
mysql> CALL TopFromBigTable('2012-04-01','2012-05-01',5);

---TRANSACTION 1484EF5C, ACTIVE 3571 sec fetching rows, thread declared inside InnoDB 193
mysql tables in use 2, locked 1
MySQL thread id 466174, OS thread handle 0x7f3616ab4700, query id 33098684 localhost    root Copying to tmp table
```

More tests:

```
mysql> CALL TopFromBigTable('2012-05-01','2012-05-04',5);
5 rows in set (1.28 sec)
mysql> CALL TopFromBigTable('2012-05-01','2012-05-05',5);
5 rows in set (1.55 sec)
mysql> CALL TopFromBigTable('2012-05-01','2012-05-06',5);
5 rows in set (1 hour 47 min 37.99 sec)
```

---

#### The details

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `BigTable` (
  `BigTableID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AnotherID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Type` char(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `StartTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `EndTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BigTableID`),
  KEY `Type` (`Type`),
  KEY `StartTime` (`StartTime`),
  KEY `EndTime` (`EndTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Query (***note in making this generic I had the `group by` wrong***)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `TopFromBigTable` (
    $StartDate DATETIME,
    $EndDate DATETIME,
    $ResultLimit INT
    )
BEGIN

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
    SELECT
        `Type`,
        COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM
        `BigTable`
    WHERE                
            `StartTime` > $StartDate
        AND
            `StartTime` < $EndDate
    GROUP BY
        `Type`
    ORDER BY
        Count DESC
    LIMIT $ResultLimit
    ;
    COMMIT;

END $$
```

Execution plan

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED ...
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: BigTable
         type: range
possible_keys: StartTime
          key: StartTime
      key_len: 8
          ref: NULL
         rows: 16446226
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

I'm running on a dedicated reporting database and so not all the normal rules apply, i.e. I read uncommitted in attempt to lower overheads since accuracy is non-critical and this database wasn't updated in the last 6 hours. I would like to benchmark how much this actually helps (if at all) but I cannot reliably time the stored procedure!

Comment: How many different `AnotherID` values are there in the table?

Comment: Almost 700,000 and probably 100,000 within a given month

Comment: I corrected `AnotherID` with `Type` which has 50 odd values and an index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tough one...If it's really a big table - adding and index in the StartTime may take a time to do and a bit of extra space but will improve select speed provided specify the USE INDEX according to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html

be sure to re-index depending on how many rows are inserted on a daily bases...use your discretion for that.

While researching your interesting issue I came across this as well : http://www.petefreitag.com/item/613.cfm

Comment: I use many indexes (yes they use a lot of space) including an index on `StartTime` and I interpret `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` as saying it is using it correctly. Those other hints could be a starting point...

Comment: I don't believe I need to [re-index](http://serverfault.com/questions/166398/when-do-i-reindex-my-mysql-database) on Innodb, nor can I benefit from [`ANALYZE TABLE`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/from-where-does-the-mysql-query-optimizer-read-index-statistics/3402#3402) so I'm running `OPTIMIZE TABLE` now .... the question still remains why the sudden jump from seconds to hours?

Comment: what version of MSSQL are you running ?

Comment: `SQL_BIG_RESULT` or `SQL_SMALL_RESULT` hints had no effect, I'm still guessing it has to do with the size of the temporary table and memory

Answer (score 0):

The detailed answer.

1. Break your stored procedure into an example query
2. Use `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`
3. Use `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` with different inputs as the optimizer can change the plan!

The random behaviour was the optimizer calculating the table statistics differently (it does so in the background over time) and choosing a less effective index. The solution is force a better index with the hint `USE INDEX(StartTime)` or adjust the indexes.

OK

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT
    `Type`,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
    `BigTable`
WHERE                
        (`StartTime` > '2012-02-01')  
    AND
        (`StartTime` < '2012-02-02' ) 
GROUP BY
    `Type`
ORDER BY
    Count DESC
LIMIT 5
;

           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: BigTable
         type: range
possible_keys: StartTime
          key: StartTime
      key_len: 8
          ref: NULL
         rows: 170986
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Bad (wrong index, 38M rows and 15% filtered)

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT
    `Type`,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
    `BigTable`
WHERE                
        (`StartTime` > '2012-02-01')  
    AND
        (`StartTime` < '2012-03-01' ) 
GROUP BY
    `Type`
ORDER BY
    Count DESC
LIMIT 5
;
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: BigTable
         type: index
possible_keys: StartTime
          key: Type
      key_len: 7
          ref: NULL
         rows: 38311434
     filtered: 14.54
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Fixed (5M rows)

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
SELECT
    `Type`,
    COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM
    `BigTable`
    USE INDEX (`StartTime`)
WHERE                
        (`StartTime` > '2012-02-01')  
    AND
        (`StartTime` < '2012-02-02' ) 
GROUP BY
    `Type`
ORDER BY
    Count DESC
LIMIT 5
;

           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: BigTable
         type: range
possible_keys: StartTime
          key: StartTime
      key_len: 8
          ref: NULL
         rows: 5572320
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you group by `Type` that has only a few (50) distinct values, and not 100K values, I see 2 options:

- A compound **`(Type, StartTime)`** index.

The index is "covering" the query, meaning the query will only use the index and not hit the table at all. It will still have to scan large parts of index and count the items per `Type`, so it's not the best one could hope but with only 50 `Type` values in the table, I think it will perform well. (The final filesort - of just 50 rows - will not be a problem.)

- Another covering index for this query would be the compound **`(StartTime, Type)`**.

If the query uses this one, it will read all the data from one part of the index so it may be faster in some cases (when the start-end time window is small and if the `Type` had many more different values). But the group by `Type` will probably make this one less performant that the first, especially with large windows.

I think the best is to test/experiment with both the above indexes and various parameters.

Comment: I've been thinking about this. Of the 50 types half the data belongs to one Type and while others Types are poorly represented - because of this could the optimizer decide to ignore Type and if so would it ignore the entire `(Type, StartTime)` index? Also the time frame is always "small" i.e. one month out of many years data.